# How old was infant considered to be in US in 1850?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century

In reading material for a course I'm doing on genealogy:

> A minor was one under 21 but over 7. An infant was usually under 8,
>   but sometimes referred to those under 21. However, in some countries
>   an infant can mean they are aged under 1 year and a child someone who
>   is over 1 but under 12 years of age.

Apparently in the 1750's an infant in the US was considered to be under 8 years but sometimes under 21 years but what about in 1850?

Comment: Where did you hear/read that "in the 1750's an infant in the US was considered to be under 8 years but sometimes under 21 years"?

Comment: In reading material for a course I'm doing on genealogy "A minor was one under 21 but over 7. An infant was usually under 8, but sometimes referred to those under 21. However, in some countries an infant can mean they are aged under 1 year and a child someone who is over 1 but under 12 years of age". Apparently this was the case in the US in the 1750's but my question is whether this was the case in 1850.

Comment: Do you have a particular case in mind? It will be easier to answer the question if we can see the context.  Also, could you add the source-of-source for your statement in your question? A reference to "reading material for a course I'm doing" doesn't help other researchers.

Comment: I found reference and answered my own question. This was part of an exam question that I answered incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve found reference to this.

source: http://www.mindserpent.com/American_History/reference/dictionaries/dictionaries_index.html  1843 Bouvier's Law Dictionary Vol 1 Page 674

> …INFANT, persons, is one under
>    the age of twenty-one years…